# can't access token value from response of data

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

i can't access token value from response of data from login api access please help me.

my code is accessing data from url and response is in json format from

my code is

```
 authFactory.login = function( username, password ){
 return $http.post('/api/login' , {
            username : username,
            password : password
        })
             .then( function (data) {

            console.log(data);

               AuthToken.setToken(data.token);
               return data;
            })
    }
```

so "data" has below response in browser.

```
     Object {data: Object, status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK", headers: function}
      config:Object
      data:Object
      message:"successfully login!"
      success:true
      token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGY1ZjZlZDhlMzcyMDA4MDhkMmU4NWQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTI1MjI1OTR9.EkTtneJvBM47LOvMUMh81XYLI_O5oByf1qjWOxliTcs"
   __proto__:Object
   headers:function (name)
   status:200
   statusText:"OK"
   __proto__: Object
```

and if i am accessing url of login api then data is occured as

```
        message:"successfully login!"
        success:true
        token:"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1OGY1ZjZlZDhlMzcyMDA4MDhkMmU4NWQiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTI1MjI1OTR9.EkTtneJvBM47LOvMUMh81XYLI_O5oByf1qjWOxliTcs"
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you want . Anyway, why are you using "data" with "*" arround ?

Comment: Please add fiddle link or what error you are getting while your are doing console.log(data); for this issue

Comment: i am callling an api and name is login Api. so i am accessing url response data  which is shown in third Code Box. so i am accessing token value with the help of "data.token" but this will show "undefined"

Comment: console.log(data); gives resonse of Second code box  and they show data properly but i am not able to access the code of "data.token"

Comment: are you able to access data.data? check in console

Comment: thanks for your help i am able to access "data.data.token". and now it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like when you are handling promise, you are calling response as `data`, try to rename it to `response` which is more human readable.
after renaming you can find data under response `response.data`.

```js
 authFactory.login = function( username, password ){
   var queryParams = {
    'username': username,
    'password': password
   }

   $http.post('/api/login' , queryParams)
  .then(function (response) {
    // replaced data with response, which is more human readable
    console.log(response.data);
    AuthToken.setToken(response.data.token);
    return response.data;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `data.json().token` ?

**EDIT**
One time happen to me that the I got confused with the response, because I named it data, and the response contained an object with the data.

In that case I had to use: **`data.data.token`**.

I hope this is also your case :)

Comment: give an error is TypeError: data.json is not a function

Comment: @MuneshKumar I've edited my answer. I hope it helps you.